# cant get the value when submitted

Tags: javascript, php

I have this in my form

```
<script>
    function changeLink(link) {
        parent.iframe_a2.location=link + "?find=" + find.value;
    }
</script>   


   <h2>Search</h2>     
   <form name="search" method="get" action="select1WSearch.php" target="iframe_a" 
     onsubmit="return changeLink('select2WSearch.php')">
   Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
     <Select NAME="field">
       <Option VALUE="no">No</option>
       <Option VALUE="CPUname">CPUname</option>
     </Select>
     <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
```

in my `select2WSearch.php`
here I will get the value of find

```
$find = ($_POST['find']) ? $_POST['find'] : $_GET['find'];
var_dump ($find);
```

The problem is when I fill up and submit the form my `select2WSearch.php` can't get the value of `name"find"`. I var_dump the this `var_dump ($find)`; but it said `string 'undefined' (length=9)`.
Help please, I need to get the value of that to the other page, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have no variable named `find` ?

Comment: Form values are not automatically passed on to JavaScript on the following page. The easiest way to go would be to do the `location` thing right away instead of submitting the form.

Comment: your form action property is `action="select1WSearch.php"` **1**, but you said _in my `select2WSearch.php`_ **2**. ??

Comment: what does `find.value`?

Answer (score 1):

This solve the problem someone post it in here but he just deleted it

```
function changeLink(link) {
     var value = document.getElementsByName('find')[0].value;
     parent.iframe_a2.location=link + "?find=" + value
}
```

In that I can get the value of `name="find"` in `select2WSearch.php`
the only problem is i also need `name="field"` value in `select2WSearch.php` just addional codes will do help pls.

Comment: its ok now, thanks to all who help.. `function changeLink(link) {
 var value1 = document.getElementsByName('find')[0].value;
  var value2 = document.getElementsByName('field')[0].value;
 parent.iframe_a2.location=link + "?find=" + value1 + "&field=" + value2`   
 

}

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you sending your data as 'get' and you trying to access those data using 'post'.try `$find = $_GET["find"];`